# How to open multiple files for output in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, output

How to open multiple files for output in VBA? If I use the

> Open OutFile For Output As outputFile

before closing the file that I opened before, I get the

> Run-time error '55':
>
> File already open.

But I need to write to both files simultaneously... Otherwise I'd need to have some kind of a buffer before writing to the file, which I have no idea how to create as I am not a VBA developer...

Edit:

```
' insert file
    insertOutputFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & ("/something" + ".insert_emergency" + emergencyNumber + "_" + getConnectionAsString(connection) + fileExtension)
    'set and open file for output
    insertFile = FreeFile()
    Open insertOutputFile For Output As insertFile


    ' delete file
    deleteOutputFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & ("/something" + ".insert_emergency" + emergencyNumber + "_" + getConnectionAsString(connection) + fileExtension)
    'set and open file for output
    deleteFile = FreeFile()
    Open deleteOutputFile For Output As deleteFile


    ' do logic with both files simultaneously

    'save
    Close #deleteFile
    Close #insertFile
```

Comment: please provide a full snippet of the code, showing how you open/close both files

Comment: @blueberryfields alright, it's there now.

Comment: It looks like insertOutputFile and deleteOutputFile are the same --- both are "/something" + ... . Shouldn't there be a difference so you get two different file names?

Comment: @xidgel Yes! Exactly! That was the problem, thank you very much! Indeed, it's one of those errors where you could probably sit alone for days, never noticing the problem while somebody else sees it. I had forgotten to change the insert part to delete there... Thanks again, you are the hero today. :)